# Formulario ignora mi validación de sesión y me redirecciona a la pagina principal

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Buen dia/noche,

He aqui mi problema, he estado probando unas cosas en PHP y MySql para practicar la validación por medio de la base de datos, pero desafortunadamente no he podido encontrar solucion a este problema, perdonenme si no lo encuentro facilmente, realmente no estoy metido en el ambito de php por eso no tengo conocimiento de este tema del todo.

En fin, el problema, como dice en el titulo, es que cuando quiero validar un usuario con un documento llamado "cedula" y su contraseña me manda a la pagina que deberia, `inicio.php`, listo todo bien ahi, pero el problema viene cuando es que me deja pasar TODO inclusive lo vacio, al solo darle a ingresar me redirecciona a esa pagina, entonces aqui mi pregunta y el respectivo codigo:

**DOCUMENTO DEL FORMULARIO (LOGIN)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="inicio.php">
        <p>Cedula:<input type="text" placeholder="Cedula" name="cedula"></p>
        <p>Password:<input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="contraseña"></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Ingresar">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**DOCUMENTO CON LA VALIDACIÓN (PHP)**

```php
<?php
$cedula=$_POST['cedula'];
$pass=$_POST['contraseña'];
session_start();
$_SESSION['cedula']=$cedula;
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","tiendadb");
$consulta="SELECT*FROM clientes where cedula='$cedula' and contra='$pass'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
$filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
if($filas){
    header("location:inicio.php");
}else{
?>
<?php
include("login.php");
?>
<h1>ERROR EN AUTENTIFICAR</h1>
<?php

}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Como se vé, uso localhost y mi base de datos se llama `"tiendadb"` con los datos de `"cedula" "contra" "nombre" "correo"`
[image: Tabla de base de datos]

No pongo `inicio.php` porque no tiene contenido del todo, solo tiene una etiqueta H1 diciendo hello world.

¿Como puedo solucionar esto, para que me tenga que aceptar la validacion?,¿ hay algo que me falta? ¿problema en la base de datos?

Gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer esto.

Comment: Evita poner "contraseña" como parámetro de envió en el input, si así lo deseas entonces debes agregar un UTF-8 en tu archivo de validación php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que veo hay un problema en tu formulario

```
 <form method="post" action="inicio.php">
```

Los formularios tienen algunas etiquetas como el methosd=POST, el cual indica de que manera se trataran los datos contenidos en los campos del FORM y como aquí lo indicas en **action="inicio.php"** le estas indicando que cuando se realiza el submit del FORM este hara el llamado al archivo inicio.php a menos que indiques otra cosa a travez del boton submit del formulario.
en action deberías poner tu archivo de validación **validacion.php** y este una vez procesados los inputs redireccionar a la pagina que desees.

Answer (score -1):

Christian: lo primero que debes hacer es validar del lado del cliente que no vengan los inputs en blanco y que tengan el formato que ameriten los inputs, esto lo haces con HTML y JavaScript o con un framework.
Luego validas del lado del servidor con la instrucción isset y cualquier otra que necesites. Otra cosa que veo es que asignas a una variable de SESSION el valor de la cédula antes de validar que se encuentre en la BD.
Por último, como consejo, deberías utilizar PDO que es mejor que mysqli y ayuda a evitar la inyección sql.